# ¿Como llamar Layouts segun su rol, dentro de las vistas?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, layout, users-roles

ando realizando un proyecto y me he topado que necesito realizar diferentes usuarios, para ser mas especifico son 4 tipos de usuarios,

> --Administrador  -- Gerente  -- contador -- Vendedor

la cuestion es la siguiente, quiero llamar un layout diferente segun sea el rol del usuario, he intentado con un **IF** pero tengo el problema de que *se me muestran las* **4 vistas de layouts al mismo tiempo,** *no importando el rol.*  Este es el codigo con el que intente

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrador') == 'Administrador')
@extends('layouts.Administrador') @else
    @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Gerente') == 'Gerente')
        @extends('layouts.Gerente')
    @else
        @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Contador') == 'Contador')
            @extends('layouts.Contador')
        @else
            @extends('layouts.Vendedor')
        @endif
    @endif
@endif
```

Tambien intente con este codigo

```
@extends(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrador') ? 'layouts.Administrador' :
(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('Gerente') ? 'layouts.Gerente' :
(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('Contador') ? 'layouts.Contador' :
(Auth::user() && Auth::user()->hasRole('Vendedor') ? 'layouts.Vendedor' ))))
```

Comment: Disculpa a que te refieres con ¿cómo esta compuesto el layout principal?

Comment: tengo 4 vistas de layouts diferentes correspondientes a su rol, y en la vista **dashboar** solo mando a llamar el layout con  @extends('layouts.Administrador')  @section('content') @endsection

Comment: Porque no anidas con un `else-if` en si la logica esta bien, ademas `hasRole` devuelve un booleano

Answer (score 1):

Una estructura de vistas típica en Laravel usa un *layout pricipal*, yo le llamo **master** o **main**, a veces tengo 2, uno para la parte pública de la web y otro para la privada.
En el *layout principal* se cargan las partes que son comunes es llamado por cada página de contenido.

Por ejemplo, un *layout* principal tiene este aspecto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('titulo')</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://@yield('canonical-url')" />
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        @include('layouts.parts.header')
        @include('layouts.parts.nav')
        @yield('content')
        @include('layouts.parts.footer')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo guardo en la carpeta 'resources/views/layouts' con el nombre 'master.blade.php'.

La página (contenido concreto), carga dentro de `@yield('content')`, así:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('titulo', 'lalala.org - Actualidad')
@section('canonical-url', 'www.lalala.org/actualidad')
@section('content')

    <article>
        <h3>Actualidad</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit ducimus ratione nisi mollitia ea accusamus officiis laboriosam officia molestiae dignissimos, vel consequatur, non beatae tenetur nam corrupti quam earum nihil!</p>
    </article>

@endsection
```

En este caso no importa donde se guarda la página o su nombre (en cuanto a la composición de vistas), pero el contenido del `@extends` y los `@section` si debe ser correcto. Fijese en que el el layout principal, que extienden las páginas concretas tengo:

```
@yield('content')
```

y en cada página que lo usa:

```
@section('content')
    <!-- contenido -->
@endsection
```

Si el `@yield` contuviera el *string* 'foo', el `@section` también requiere el *string* 'foo' que el contenido cargue en el lugar que ocupa el `@yield`.

Ahora, cuando añadimos partes concretas a una página de forma condicional, ya sea porque el contenido es para un rol determinado o cualquier otro motivo, usamos `@import`. Por ejemplo, si como en tu caso tienes *layouts* con contenido específico para cada rol, deberías cargarlos como sigue:

```
@include('layouts.roles.admin')
```

Siguiendo mi ejemplo:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('titulo', 'lalala.org - Actualidad')
@section('canonical-url', 'www.lalala.org/actualidad')
@section('content')

    <article>
        <h3>Actualidad</h3>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit ducimus ratione nisi mollitia ea accusamus officiis laboriosam officia molestiae dignissimos, vel consequatur, non beatae tenetur nam corrupti quam earum nihil!</p>

        @if (Auth::user()->hasRole('admin'))
            @include('layouts.roles.admin')
        @endif
    </article>

@endsection
```

> Editado

Todo se complica bastante en cualquier proyecto. La organización es fundamental.

Nunca usaría la idea de *layouts* por rol, sería mejor llamarles *templates*, porque no son lo mismo*, y pueden tener sentido si cada rol tiene bloques muy específicos de contenido, como menús de opciones muy específicas por rol. Los guardaría en 'resources/views/roles' antes que en 'resources/views/layouts/roles'.

Un template no tiene una función "estructural", como los layouts, sólo contenido, como un párrafo:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit ducimus ratione nisi mollitia ea accusamus officiis laboriosam officia molestiae dignissimos, vel consequatur, non beatae tenetur nam corrupti quam earum nihil!</p>
```

Este podría ser un tamplate y estar en su propio fichero, que cargaras en alguna otra parte con `@include`.

Otra cuestion, la línea:

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Gerente') == 'Gerente')
```

debería ser:

```
@if (Auth::user()->hasRole('Gerente'))
```

una función llamada `hasRole()` que recibe como parámetro el nombre del rol debe hacer la comparación internamente y devolver un *booleano*.

Comment: gracias por ese aporte, ya te comprendi mejor, pero funcionaria si solo tuviera un solo usuario , ya que mande a llamar a @section en la vista correcta, pero si tuviera diferentes usuarios con diferentes vistas, ahi se complica un poco mas por eso es que solo queria mandar a llamar los layouts con una condicion cual se su ID_ROLE

Comment: @Orici te recomiendo además le anexes al OP esto: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#if-statements por que su estructura de condicionales esta mal hecha y que cheque acá sobre los roles por que lo tiene igualmente mal https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v3/basic-usage/role-permissions mientras mi +1, Geovanni esta respuesta es excelente te recomiendo la leas a detalle

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo la logica que hicistes esta bien, solo faltaria ordenarlo por un `else-if` para que solo se ejecute una vez y te muestre lo que quieres, de la siguiente manera:

```
@if ( Auth::user()->hasRole('Administrador') )
    @extends('layouts.Administrador')
@elseif ( Auth::user()->hasRole('Gerente') )
    @extends('layouts.Gerente')
@elseif ( Auth::user()->hasRole('Contador') )
    @extends('layouts.Contador')
@else
    @extends('layouts.Vendedor')
@endif
```

Por otra parte hasRole devuelve un `booleano(true-false)`, por lo cual no es necesario comparar por el mismo rol otra vez

Comment: @BetaM pero por esa razon estoy quitando la comparasion. A menos que el OP tenga un funcion llamada `hasRole` y esta le devuelve el nombre del rol

Comment: @BetaM entiendo, pero es posible que haya hecho lo que dije? Crear una funcion `hasRole`? Si es asi, entonces esta bien la comparasion, aunque es mejor pregunta aun cuando es evidente